# When using D3 in React, should I use useRef, or directly select an element by tag/class/Id with D3?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, d3.js, react-hooks

```
<div ref={svgRef} className="App"></div>
```

***For this given div which method is best***

**a)**

```
const svg = d3.select('.App')
      .append('svg')
      .attr('width', width + margin.left + margin.right)
      .attr('height', width + margin.top + margin.bottom);
```

**b)**

```
const svgRef = useRef();
const svg = d3.select(svgRef.current)
      .append('svg')
      .attr('width', width + margin.left + margin.right)
      .attr('height', width + margin.top + margin.bottom);
```

Comment: You are actually asking why to use refs in React, its not related to d3. Try reading the docs: https://reactjs.org/docs/refs-and-the-dom.html#:~:text=Refs%20provide%20a%20way%20to,components%20interact%20with%20their%20children.

Answer (score 2):

Both approaches work, but the first one is more error prone since D3 can accidentally interact with unrelated components, such as when other components have elements with the same class being selected.

The useRef approach guarantees the correct selection, so it should be preferred when possible.

Comment: Some confusion, OP suggested useRef first and by element-selection second. Your answer suggests that useRef is both more error-prone and preferred.